# Optaplanner web examples - No poly line map updates ending with GC OutOfMemory

Tags: java, optaplanner

My development environment consists of

NetBeans 8.1

Wildfly 10.1.0

JDK8

VM Options -Xms4G -Xmx4G

I am running the Optaplanner Google maps web example vehicle routing war in the setup above which is failing due to GC OutOfMemery errors.

In the IDE logs I see when the application is running

```
VehicleRoutingSolution belgium-road-time-n50-k10 has 1 depots, 10 vehicles and 49 customers with a search space of 10^95.
```

The above logging continues for hours until Java calls a GC OutOfMemory error.

During the processing I also do not see any route poly lines being drawn on the Google map.

Should I expect the poly lines to change as the planning problem is being solved

Logging the ajax success response from updateSolution within googleMaps.jsp to the console generates

```
{"name":"belgium-road-time-n50-k10","customerList":[{"locationName":"ANTHISNES","latitude":50.4812987,"longitude":5.5198048,"demand":15},{"locationName":"AVE-ET-AUFFE","latitude":50.1085676,"longitude":5.1429583,"demand":16},{"locationName":"BAVIKHOVE","latitude":50.8753581,"longitude":3.3113744,"demand":31},{"locationName":"BERSILLIES-L'ABBAYE","latitude":50.2624949,"longitude":4.1523037,"demand":14},{"locationName":"BLERET","latitude":50.688785,"longitude":5.2859129,"demand":33},{"locationName":"BOURLERS","latitude":50.025208,"longitude":4.3409814,"demand":7},{"locationName":"BULSKAMP","latitude":51.0432467,"longitude":2.6501345,"demand":9},{"locationName":"CHIEVRES","latitude":50.5661351,"longitude":3.7853169,"demand":17},{"locationName":"DAMME","latitude":51.2365829,"longitude":3.3400765,"demand":33},{"locationName":"DONSTIENNES","latitude":50.2849958,"longitude":4.3106966,"demand":26},{"locationName":"ELVERDINGE","latitude":50.8848669,"longitude":2.8162074,"demand":18},{"locationName":"EVELETTE","latitude":50.411922,"longitude":5.173705,"demand":10},{"locationName":"FONTAINE-L'EVEQUE","latitude":50.4100558,"longitude":4.3249526,"demand":32},{"locationName":"GELINDEN","latitude":50.7670559,"longitude":5.2628934,"demand":26},{"locationName":"GONDREGNIES","latitude":50.6271045,"longitude":3.9115699,"demand":14},{"locationName":"GUIGNIES","latitude":50.5499808,"longitude":3.3727285,"demand":32},{"locationName":"HAREN_BRUSSEL","latitude":50.8919578,"longitude":4.4182942,"demand":33},{"locationName":"HEPPIGNIES","latitude":50.4814121,"longitude":4.4932598,"demand":30},{"locationName":"HOFSTADE_BT.","latitude":50.9912912,"longitude":4.492735,"demand":25},{"locationName":"HUMBEEK","latitude":50.9667658,"longitude":4.3834362,"demand":18},{"locationName":"JURBISE","latitude":50.5208191,"longitude":3.9017078,"demand":26},{"locationName":"KOMEN","latitude":50.77614,"longitude":3.007366,"demand":2},{"locationName":"LANDEGEM","latitude":51.0566021,"longitude":3.573045,"demand":25},{"locationName":"LES_BONS_VILLERS","latitude":50.5427462,"longitude":4.4476802,"demand":10},{"locationName":"LISSEWEGE","latitude":51.2948381,"longitude":3.1994146,"demand":3},{"locationName":"MAFFLE","latitude":50.6200815,"longitude":3.8018102,"demand":28},{"locationName":"MAULDE","latitude":50.6165736,"longitude":3.5470846,"demand":9},{"locationName":"MERKSPLAS","latitude":51.361787,"longitude":4.861625,"demand":21},{"locationName":"MONT_NAM.","latitude":50.3534706,"longitude":4.9014191,"demand":7},{"locationName":"NAAST","latitude":50.5504316,"longitude":4.0964803,"demand":24},{"locationName":"NIEUWKERKEN-WAAS","latitude":51.1936164,"longitude":4.1787815,"demand":1},{"locationName":"OLLIGNIES","latitude":50.6876172,"longitude":3.8574228,"demand":5},{"locationName":"ORET","latitude":50.2998711,"longitude":4.6155651,"demand":19},{"locationName":"PEPINGEN","latitude":50.7360287,"longitude":4.1360863,"demand":4},{"locationName":"POUPEHAN","latitude":49.8122243,"longitude":5.0029,"demand":9},{"locationName":"RENINGE","latitude":50.9477884,"longitude":2.7891722,"demand":7},{"locationName":"ROSMEER","latitude":50.8460854,"longitude":5.5750235,"demand":16},{"locationName":"SAINT-MARTIN","latitude":50.5009515,"longitude":4.6473657,"demand":27},{"locationName":"SELANGE","latitude":49.6096472,"longitude":5.8560275,"demand":15},{"locationName":"SINT-KWINTENS-LENNIK","latitude":50.8068661,"longitude":4.1538281,"demand":17},{"locationName":"SOMZEE","latitude":50.2950667,"longitude":4.4831638,"demand":20},{"locationName":"TAILLES","latitude":50.2273877,"longitude":5.7437507,"demand":27},{"locationName":"TILFF","latitude":50.5695196,"longitude":5.5844061,"demand":33},{"locationName":"VAUX-LEZ-ROSIERES","latitude":49.9102794,"longitude":5.5659053,"demand":18},{"locationName":"VILLERS-L'EVEQUE","latitude":50.7044254,"longitude":5.4399729,"demand":31},{"locationName":"VOSSEM","latitude":50.8346073,"longitude":4.557627,"demand":19},{"locationName":"WARNANT-DREYE","latitude":50.5951652,"longitude":5.2276287,"demand":24},{"locationName":"WETTEREN","latitude":51.0005742,"longitude":3.8693544,"demand":16},{"locationName":"XHENDELESSE","latitude":50.6061517,"longitude":5.7830075,"demand":32}],"vehicleRouteList":[{"depotLocationName":"BRUSSEL","depotLatitude":50.8427501,"depotLongitude":4.3515499,"hexColor":"#8ae234","capacity":125,"demandTotal":0,"customerList":[]},{"depotLocationName":"BRUSSEL","depotLatitude":50.8427501,"depotLongitude":4.3515499,"hexColor":"#fce94f","capacity":125,"demandTotal":0,"customerList":[]},{"depotLocationName":"BRUSSEL","depotLatitude":50.8427501,"depotLongitude":4.3515499,"hexColor":"#729fcf","capacity":125,"demandTotal":0,"customerList":[]},{"depotLocationName":"BRUSSEL","depotLatitude":50.8427501,"depotLongitude":4.3515499,"hexColor":"#e9b96e","capacity":125,"demandTotal":0,"customerList":[]},{"depotLocationName":"BRUSSEL","depotLatitude":50.8427501,"depotLongitude":4.3515499,"hexColor":"#ad7fa8","capacity":125,"demandTotal":0,"customerList":[]},{"depotLocationName":"BRUSSEL","depotLatitude":50.8427501,"depotLongitude":4.3515499,"hexColor":"#73d216","capacity":125,"demandTotal":0,"customerList":[]},{"depotLocationName":"BRUSSEL","depotLatitude":50.8427501,"depotLongitude":4.3515499,"hexColor":"#edd400","capacity":125,"demandTotal":0,"customerList":[]},{"depotLocationName":"BRUSSEL","depotLatitude":50.8427501,"depotLongitude":4.3515499,"hexColor":"#3465a4","capacity":125,"demandTotal":0,"customerList":[]},{"depotLocationName":"BRUSSEL","depotLatitude":50.8427501,"depotLongitude":4.3515499,"hexColor":"#c17d11","capacity":125,"demandTotal":0,"customerList":[]},{"depotLocationName":"BRUSSEL","depotLatitude":50.8427501,"depotLongitude":4.3515499,"hexColor":"#75507b","capacity":125,"demandTotal":0,"customerList":[]}],"feasible":false,"distance":null}
```

Should I expect feasible to return as true at some point.

Kind regards,
Ian.

Comment: That's weird. What version of optaplanner(-webexamples) is this? There an arquillian unit test to test it on wildfly and 4G of heap should be far more than sufficient. Can you copy paste the entire stacktrace of that OutOfMemory error? Maybe try connecting with VisualVM to verify that it indeed has a heap space of larger than 512MB.

Comment: If you're into docker, Bilgin has made [a docker image of optaplanner-webexamples on wildfly](https://hub.docker.com/r/bibryam/optaplanner-webexamples/) - although it's not an official one yet - we're going to look at how to automate that during our release procedure.

Comment: It ran for 9 hours yesterday before halting. I had visualvm running during that time where it was showing a steady increase in heap up to around 3.5gb  over the duration of the run

Comment: The build I am using is the prebuilt binary 6.4.0.final

Comment: No need to run it for hours. This is not normal. Can you again connect with visualvm and use the sampler or profiler to grab a memory dump to see if anything sticks out? Specifically filter it on package "org.optaplanner" and maybe share a screenshot here. I would expect just a few (maybe 3 or so) VehicleRoutingSolution instances and 1 or a few Solver instances, for example.